# Adding columns and index to sum up values using Panda in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file, after reading it using Panda I have this output

```
     Year Month   Brunei Darussalam   ...   Thailand    Viet Nam    Myanmar 
348  2007   Jan                 3813  ...       25863       12555       4887
349  2007   Feb                 3471  ...       22575       11969       3749
350  2007   Mar                 4547  ...       33087       14060       5480
351  2007   Apr                 3265  ...       34500       15553       6838
352  2007   May                 3641  ...       30555       14995       5295
..    ...   ...                  ...  ...         ...         ...        ...
474  2017   Jul                 5625  ...       48620       71153      12619
475  2017   Aug                 4610  ...       40993       51866      10934
476  2017   Sep                 5387  ...       39692       40270       9888
477  2017   Oct                 4202  ...       61448       39013      11616
478  2017   Nov                 5258  ...       39304       36964      11402
```

I use this to get me the sum of all countries within the total years to display top 3

```
top3_country = new_df.iloc[0:, 2:9].sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(3)
```

though my output is this

```
  Indonesia       27572424
  Malaysia        11337420
  Philippines      6548622
```

I want to add columns and index into the sum value as if it was a new dataframe like this

```
    Countries       Visitors
  0 Indonesia       27572424
  1 Malaysia        11337420
  2 Philippines      6548622
```

Sorry I am just starting to learn learn Panda any help will be gladly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great resource on how to ask questions.  We love data not to be in images and we really encourage people to try some code before they ask a question so you can show some work.

Comment: i will remember not to use images for my next questions pardon me but this is my first question asked on the hub ty for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for 2 columns `DataFrame` and then set new columns names from list:

```
top3_country = top3_country.reset_index()
top3_country.columns = ['Countries', 'Visitors']
```

Or use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
top3_country = top3_country.rename_axis('Countries').reset_index(name='Visitors')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return back `pd.DataFrame`, use `reset_index`, and `rename`. Change your code to:

```
import pandas as pd
top3_country = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0:, 2:9].sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(3)
                            ).reset_index(
                                ).rename(columns={'index':'Countries',0:'visitors'})
top3_country

  Countries  visitors
0  Indonesia   27572424
1  Malaysia    11337420
2  Philippines  6548622
```